# How to find someone's personal best? (fastest time in a race?)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently making a minigame to play right now, (specifically a racing game) but I am unsure how to find the personal best of a player at the end of the game. I have a timer setup, but my objectives seem to make this task a little difficult? I know the scores of the times will play into this, so I will explain what I have setup with the times.

1.) I have objectives, dispsecond and dispminute.
These stand for Display Second and Display Minute. Simply, it functions as a normal timer. At the end of race, everyones' timers halt. So at the end of the race, one's score may be:
1-dispminute 39-dispsecond

Now my question still stands, how do I find the personal best?

Comment: Are you doing this with redstone or command blocks? If you're using any number of command blocks (which it looks like) you shouldn't have any redstone, and therefore shouldn't tag your question as such.

Comment: Sorry I just changed my question. Could you read that? (With command blocks)

Comment: Save the time and update their best time whenever you encounter a faster time.

Comment: +GiantTree but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use scoreboard operations

I assume you also have the time stored in a non-formatted scoreboard, e.g. in ticks. Let's call that objective `time`. If not, see below.

Make another dummy scoreboard objective called `best`, and initalize it to 0, e.g. by running

```
/scoreboard players add @a best 0
```

When a player finishes the race, mark him in some way, e.g. by assigning a tag (I'll use `tag=finished`). Then simply run

```
/execute @a[tag=finished] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] best < @a[c=1] time
```

The `<` operator will assign the lesser score of `best` and `time` to `best`. The `execute` makes sure that both targets of the scoreboard command are the same player.

You can turn `best` into `bestminute` and `bestsecond` the same way you converted `time` into the display stats.

#### Converting times to a single number

If you *don't* have time stored as a single continuously increasing number, you can use `scoreboard players operation` commands to turn your `dispminute` and `dispseconds` scores into one. Set up the new objective, and store the number 60 in a fake player (called #SIXTY):

```
/scoreboard objectives add time dummy
/scoreboard players set #SIXTY time 60
```

Now, set up a repeat/chain line and run.

```
/scoreboard players set @a time 0
/execute @a ~ ~ ~  /scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] time += @a[c=1] dispminutes
/execute @a ~ ~ ~  /scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] time *= #SIXTY time
/execute @a ~ ~ ~  /scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] time += @a[c=1] dispsecond
```

This will first reset the time score for every player. Then, the players' scores in `dispminutes` will be added to `time`, and multiplied by 60. Lastly, `dispseconds` is added to time.

Comment: Ok, I just did a little tweaking, and it all works flawlessly. But, just one more thing MrLemon. You said 'You can turn best into bestminute and bestsecond the same way you converted time into the display stats.' I'm not so sure how to do that. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the largest dispminute and then the ones that are the same dispminute check for the largest dispsecond. If you would like I could make my own version for example... But since I'm more of a redstone I would use items to count... That just me though.